# How can I print everything before a match?

Tags: linux, awk

After I run `hostname` I get the [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) like so:

```
$ hostname
foo.mydomain.xyz
```

I'd like to only get the short name `foo` so I can store it as a variable in a script.  I've tried some ways with `awk` by matching `.` (the dot) but haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using `awk`

```
$ echo foo.mydomain.xyz | awk -F. '{print $1}'
foo
```

awk takes its input by "records" (which defaults to lines) and each record is divided into "fields."  By default, fields are separated by white space.  Here, we change the default so that the field separator is a period.  For this example, that means that the first field is `foo`, the second is `mydomain`, and the third is `xyz`.  We tell awk to print only the first field, `foo`.

To capture the short name to a shell variable:

```
shortname=$(hostname | awk -F. '{print $1}')
```

#### Using `sed`

This problem can also be solved with `sed`:

```
$ echo foo.mydomain.xyz | sed 's/\..*//'
foo
```

Here, the substitution command, `s/\..*//`, simply looks for a period and removes the period and all that follows.

#### Using shell

```
$ name=foo.mydomain.xyz
$ name=${name%%.*}
$ echo $name
foo
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to use sed, awk, grep. Just use the `-s` flag of `hostname`:

```
$ hostname -s
foo
```

From the man page:

```
  -s, --short
        Display the short host name. This is the host name cut at the first dot.
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't know that.  I should've looked at the man page.  Thank you!